# Crop background image inside axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics

I have a PDF file and I want to use a subset of this image as a background for a Tikz axis:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        grid=both,
        xmin=-30, xmax=30,
        ymin=0, ymax=45,
        set layers]
        \addplot[thick, color=blue, on layer=axis background]
        graphics[xmin=-180,ymin=-90,xmax=180,ymax=90] {borders.pdf};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work as the image is shown in the background:

[image]

On a `standalone`, the background is only visible on the side of the axis, but on a normal document, I can see the whole image. If I remove `on layer=axis background`, the image is cropped as expected, but then it's on the foreground, which I do not want (it's above the grid lines for instance).

I would like the background to stop at the axis boundary, is it possible?

---

Whole code if necessary (can use any image for the background):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    grid=both,
    xmin=-30, xmax=30,
    ymin=0, ymax=45,
    clip=true,
    set layers]
    \addplot[thick, color=blue, on layer=axis background]
    graphics[xmin=-180,ymin=-90,xmax=180,ymax=90] {borders.pdf};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you remove `on layer=axis background` and add `axis on top` to the `axis` options, does that do what you're after?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Almost, the background is ok but now if I plot something on top it's below the grid lines.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. It works if I add `on layer=axis foreground` to the other plots. I'll just have to crop these manually but I can deal with this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `clip mode=individual` to the `axis` options, then clipping will work for the image, even with `on layer=axis background`.

This is actually mentioned in the description of `on layer` in the `pgfplots` manual:

> Note that if you have two *plots* with different values of `on layer`, you may also want to enable `clip mode=clip individual` or to deactivate clipping altogether using `clip=false`. Clipping options need
>   to be provided as option to the axis, not to the plot. The technical background is that clip paths needs
>   to be replicated for the layer on which the drawing is supposed to happen – otherwise they will be applied to the wrong layer.

(section 4.27.3 *Changing the Layer of Graphical Elements*, page 411, in the manual for `pgfplots` version 1.16, dated 2018/03/28.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    grid=both,
    grid style={blue}, % just to make it obvious with the given image
    xmin=-30, xmax=30,
    ymin=0, ymax=45,
    clip=true,
    set layers,
    clip mode=individual % <-- add this
]
    \addplot[thick, color=blue, on layer=axis background]
    graphics[xmin=-180,ymin=-90,xmax=180,ymax=90] {example-image};


\addplot [very thick,red] {rand*30+20};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```